# Program for creating a Keyboard "CheatSheet"

Tags: layout, keyboard, latex

I'm already searching for a while for a program to create a kind of Keyboard Cheatsheet [like this](http://www.digitalcombatsimulator.com/upload/iblock/a6d/dcs_a10c_keyboard.png):

[image]

The [Keyboard Designer](http://www.qliner.com/hotkeys/designertutorial.htm) unfortunally doesn't support writing text below the keys.

It should be a program Windows or Linux. Also a good template in TeX would help.

Comment: How about this one?: http://www.keyboard-layout-editor.com ([source at GitHub](https://github.com/ijprest/keyboard-layout-editor))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because I didn't found any program or TeX-Template for this, I used a picture from katsbits.com as template.

For anyone who want to do the same in a shorter time, [here](http://root.gu471.de/files/keymap.xcf) the GIMP-File. It will be looks like[image]

Comment: File is down. Please upload again.

Comment: The file is not available again, please update the link.

Comment: I've tried it and it's downloadable even from IPv4/6 and IPv4only networks. Maybe you tried to download it in the small update phase yesterday, when I updated the server. Please try again. If it won't work for you, just write me a mail. I'll send you the file.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I missed it (SO needs some way of "watching" questions/answers of other people...). The link still gives me "404 Not Found" from home and two servers in different countries. I don't really need the file anymore, it took some time, but I made the keyboard in LaTeX. You can see it in use [here](https://vifm.info/cheatsheets.shtml) (link to the source is below the image).